# Python memory runaway when lambdifying huge list of functions

Tags: python, memory, lambda

I have a huge list of SymPy functions (essentially string representations of functional expressions). What I need to do is to turn those symbolic functions into NumPy functions, for multiple efficient evaluations, using lambdify. Lambdify essentially just takes a string representation of a function, concatenates a "lambda *args:" in front (args list has to be supplied) and passes that to eval(). Well, obviously there's more to it than that, but the internal details are not important here. It seems like it would be very convenient to just do something like:

```
f = lambdify(args,str(list_of_functions),"numpy")
```

And it does work in fact. This creates a function f(*args) that for a given set of parameter values returns a list of all the original functions evaluated. So the final effect is exactly what I need.

The problem is that when the list_of_functions is very big, the compilation of the lambda takes huge amounts of memory (around 1GiB for 50,000 functions). This memory is freed immediately after the lambda is returned, but if it's not available at the time of the compilation, the system will just kill the python process. My question is, what's happening here and is there some clever way of going around that huge memory consumption?

Comment: Can you process the strings in batches?

Comment: You mean to just handle just a couple of thousand functions at a time and make that into a lambda, and then combine those into a single lambda at the end? That's an interesting idea, although I'm not sure if I can apply it. The reason is that I'm actually using that list as an argument to a sparse matrix, so I'm passing the whole thing at once. But it's a csr matrix, so maybe I can just do it row by row? I'm not sure, the sparse module documentation is a bit incomplete. I'll look into that.